# How do I use a trained Matlab Neural Network to Python for detection purpose

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I have trained a Neural Network using a Matlab Neural Network Toolbox, particularly using the command nntool. The detection is basically for traffic sign and I have used a database of 90 traffic images(no-entry,no right and stop signs), each of 30 images of size 8*8 pixels of which no-entry signs are taken positive. My input is 64*90 and target as 1*90. Now, I need to use this neural network in Python for real-time recognition. What parameters do I need? I am completely new to neural networking.[Here's the link to an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkjnt.png) [Here's my link to the weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QamL.png)

Comment: Please how did you get the neural network toolbox did you pay for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to take the weights of your neural network.
An example:

```
[x,t] = simplefit_dataset;
net = feedforwardnet(20);
net = train(net,x,t);
wb = getwb(net)
```

Then I also suggest that you read on [ANN structure](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html), this will help you understand how the output of a neural network is calculated, given the weights. Then you can adapt it to your own needs and using that calculate an output in Python.

Comment: I went through this a while ago and I am still a newbie in neural networking. I am trying to implement the trained network(in my case is network1) in Python similar to face detection. Is there a way I can achieve that in real time detection? I have attached a link to the weights which I think is you are talking to.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/165233-neural-network-how-does-neural-network-calculate-output-from-net-iw-net-lw-net-b)?

Comment: I have calculated the output. But now the problem is how do I use that particular output matrix to detect the real-time image of traffic signs in python?(I am using raspberry pi for my project so want to implement in python)

Comment: Weights are not "the output". You should use them to calculate one. A [simple example](http://i.imgur.com/yE88Ryt.png) with two inputs, 3 neurons in the hidden layer and one output neuron. You could share the structure of your network, it would be easier to help you.